# How to sort an struct of parabolas after their vertex height, using qsort?

Tags: c, quicksort, qsort

I got a problem where I have to first create a function that calculates the vertex height of a given `struct` of parabolas and returns `0` for parabola and `1` if not. Then sort them with `qsort` using the vertex height as parameter which ascends. Also if `a == 0` (not a parabola), those will be sorted after the parabolas. Then I have to use a test-main to print example-parabolas and see if they got sorted correctly.

I think I got the calculation of vertex height, but I have no clue what I have to write into the function for `qsort`. I'm kinda new to programming and have not quite gotten the concept of pointers in c.

The given **header.h**:

```
#ifndef header
#define header 1

struct parabola {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

int vertexheight(struct parabola *p, double *y);
void sort_parabola(struct parabola *p, int n);

#endif
```

**my program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int compare();

int vertexheight(struct parabola *p, double *y) {
    int rc = 0;
        
    if (p->a == 0) {
        rc = 1;
    } else {
        *y = p->c - ((p->b * p->b) / (4 * p->a));
    }
      
    return rc;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {

    //?

    return 0;
}

void sort_parabola(struct parabola *p, int n) {
    qsort(p, n, sizeof(struct parabola), compare);  
}

int main() {
    struct parabola p[] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {2,5,-19}, {0,-100,-56}, {-967,24,-24}, {36,2,70},
        {5,72,0}, {75,-4,55}, {20,41,7},
        {-1,0,0}
    };
    double y;
    int i, size = sizeof(p) / sizeof(struct parabola);
    
    sort_parabola(p, sizeof(p) / sizeof(struct parabola)); 
 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        
        //output
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot if someone can help me with this.

**Edit:**

```
int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2) {
    
    const struct parabola *p1 = (const struct parabola *)vp1;
    const struct parabola *p2 = (const struct parabola *)vp2;
    double h1, h2;
    int rc1, rc2;
    rc1 = vertexheight(p1, &h1);
    rc2 = vertexheight(p2, &h2);
    
    if (h1 < h2) return -1;
    if (h1 > h2) return 1;
    if (h1 == h2) return 0;
    if (vertexheight((struct parabola*)p1, &h1) == 1)
        return 1; //here I try to sort parabolas with a == 0 at the end of the list, because they have no vertex, doesn't work yet
    
    return 0;   
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I Think my function works now as intended

```
int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2) { 
    double h1, h2;
    
    struct parabola *p1 = (struct parabola *)vp1;
    struct parabola *p2 = (struct parabola *)vp2;
    
    vertexheight(p1, &h1);
    vertexheight(p2, &h2);
    
    if (vertexheight(p1, &h1) == 0 && vertexheight(p2, &h2) == 0){
    
        if (h1 < h2) return -1;
        if (h1 > h2) return 1;
        if (h1 == h2) return 0; 
    }
    
    else if (vertexheight(p1, &h1) != 0 && vertexheight(p2, &h2) == 0) {
        
        return 1;       
    }
    
    else if (vertexheight(p1, &h1) == 0 && vertexheight(p2, &h2) != 0) {
        
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
        return 0;
}

void sort_parabola(struct parabola *p, int n) {
    qsort(p, n, sizeof(struct parabola), compare);
}
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials and examples of using `qsort` on the Internet.  Can you try following one of them and, if you get stuck, explain where?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried using the tutorials, I think I know that I have to compare a and b and return -1, 0 or 1 to give qsort something to work with, also return 1 if my p->a == 0. I'm stuck on how I reference my struct parabola with my vertexheight function and the vertexheight *y to be written into a and b and compare the results.

Comment: I think I got the answer (see edit 2).

Comment: Your new version looks mostly good, but a couple comments: (1) try saving the return value of the two `vertexheight` calls in variables, e.g. `int r1 = vertexheight(p1, &h1);` and then you can just compare `r1` with `r2` in the later tests, instead of calling `vertexheight` over and over again, which is inefficient.  (2) If both "parabolas" have 0 as their `a` term (so they are both lines), such as for `3x-2` and `8x+9`, your compare function will always return 0, telling `qsort` that they are equivalent and could be placed in either order.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! Yes, I have to sort the parabolas, but for the lines it does not matter how they are sorted as long as the parabolas come first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to your `compare` function are pointers to the two objects (here `struct parabola`) that you need to compare; you just need to cast them in order to use them as such.  It's often convenient to create some temporary pointer variables of the appropriate type, and then use them to access the objects, so as to only have to write the cast once.  I'm changing the names of the arguments from `a,b` to `p1, p2` to avoid confusion with the `a,b,c` members of your `struct`.

```
int compare(const void * vp1, const void * vp2) {
    const struct parabola * p1 = (const struct parabola *)vp1;
    const struct parabola * p2 = (const struct parabola *)vp2;
    double h1, h2;
    int rc1, rc2;
    rc1 = vertexheight(p1, &h1); // now h1 contains the vertexheight of the first parabola
    rc2 = vertexheight(p2, &h2);
    // deal with these as you wish
    // return -1, 0, 1 as appropriate
}
```

As a side note, don't use declarations like `int compare();` which leave parameter types unspecified.  Always use a full prototype: `int compare(const void *, const void *);`  Likewise, when defining `main` you should write `int main(void) {` not `int main() {`.

Comment: Note that the cast from `const void *` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

The sorting works now. But I get a warning:
expected 'struct parabola *' but argument is of type 'const struct parabola *'

I have to use -Wall and warnings are not allowed

Comment: `vertexheight` doesn't modify the object which its `p` argument points to, so it should be declared as `const`, i.e. `int vertexheight(const struct parabola *p, double *y) { ...`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the header.h. Is there a work-around?

Comment: You can declare `p1, p2` without `const`: `struct parabola *p1 = (struct parabola *)vp1;`.  This is legal so long as you take care never to actually modify the object that they point to, though it's generally not good practice.  In this case the cast is needed to silence a warning about casting `const` to non-`const` - as dbush says, in the version with `const` it could be dropped.

Comment: @Moepius: I would also suggest reporting the missing `const` as a bug in the provided header file.

Comment: Okay thanks, the warning disapperaed after I removed const. I also got a warning that rc1/rc2 are set. but not used. How do I fix this properly (don't want to make random after calculation after return 0;)? 

And last thing, I want to sort non-parables with a == 0 at the end of the list, that happens when return value of vertexheight is rc = 1. I tried to do:  if (vertexheight((struct parabola*)p1, &h1) == 1) return 1;  but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Moepius: If you don't want them then don't set them - just don't assign the return of `vertexheight` to anything.  But always returning `1` when the first parabola has `a == 0` seems wrong.  What if you have two different parabolas that both have `a == 0`?

Comment: @Moepius: Anyway, I think I've answered your original question about the syntax for  a compare function for `qsort`.  The actual logic within that function is really more for you to figure out as part of your assignment.

Comment: Okay, yes, I think I'll figure out the rest by myself. Thank's for your help!